# Android app submission to Amazon App store failed

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

I couldn't find any resource for Amazon app store submission help, so I hope somebody here know what went wrong.

In the binary upload part, I got this error:

```
The bundle seems to be corrupted or invalid, see error below.
[File: Appfilename.apk] Unable to parse Android app bundle [There was a problem parsing the resources.arsc file.]
```

I can't tell what seems to be the problem, the same file submited fine on Google Market.

Comment: You're going to make us guess without showing any concrete information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have Licence verification Library for Google?

My guess (purely guess) is that the DRM library for Amazon might be different from Googles LVL

Comment: How did u resolve the issue? Once you resolve it see if you can share the approach.